# What function returns all possible permutations with repeating list elements?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I want to find a sample space of such experiment:
There are three exits from the box: Left (L), right (R) and front (F). Three mice have been put in that box. Find the sample space of an event which mouse has chosen which exit. Function Permutations[] gives all different outputs.

```
L={L,R,F}
Permutations[L]
```

How can I find also outcomes like {F,F,L}, {R,R,R}... ?

Comment: Voting to close, since the problem has nothing to do with permutations.

Comment: It's only terminology. The OP has to state if he/she wants variations or combinations. (In other words: Is (LLF) the same as (LFL)?)

Comment: @Stefan No, no, the problem is the recursive definitions. The `L={L,R,F}`. Permutation works as expected.

Comment: yep, sounds like he wants Tuples and is confused about the meaning of Permutations

Comment: @Ajasja When I use your example, I don't get the event `{RRR}` which the OP demanded. So `Permutations` does NOT give the asked results.

Comment: @Misery Please try to re-state your question in an easier to understand way, to avoid all these close and reopen votes.  I'd suggest giving an example input and the complete output your desire.

Comment: Question should be restated as: Given a list of 3 distinct objects, how does one form the list of all possible triples of these objects, repetitions allowed?

Comment: @Stefan Ahh, you're right.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've got my answer anyway :]

Comment: I disagree that his question is too localize: 4 upvotes and 6 upvotes on accepted answer shows that it is helping new visitors. I suggest removing the closure by lack of evidence supporting localization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 Tuples[{l, r, f}, 3]
 (* {{l, l, l}, {l, l, r}, {l, l, f}, {l, r, l}, {l, r, r}, {l, r, f}, 
    {l, f, l}, {l, f, r}, {l, f, f}, {r, l, l}, {r, l, r}, {r, l, f}, 
    {r,  r, l}, {r, r, r}, {r, r, f}, {r, f, l}, {r, f, r}, {r, f, f},
    {f, l,  l}, {f, l, r}, {f, l, f}, {f, r, l}, {f, r, r}, {f, r, f}, 
    {f, f,  l}, {f, f, r}, {f, f, f}} *)
```

?

Answer (score 3):

The only problem is that you have a recursive definition ( you want `L` to be a list and outcome).

In general **using identifiers that start with a capital letter is best avoided.** `D` and `C` are some examples of this.

This is much safer and works as expected:

```
list = {"L", "R", "F"}
Permutations[list]
```

If you would like to have ["permutations with repetition"](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) then `Tuples` is the right tool for the job (as [kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19792/745) already noted):

```
Tuples[list, 3]
```

Comment: And `E`, and `I`, and `N`, and `O`...